# ‘dominated’ or 'shadowed'

Tags: word-choice

> The second term is shadowed by the first term.

I tend to mean that the first term is much bigger than the second term. Of course we can use the word 'dominated' here. But this word has been used many times in my paper, so I would like to rephrase it somehow.

Is 'shadowed' a good or appropriate choice?

It is a scientific paper about quantum mechanics.

Comment: If you could give the context that is helpful.  What is the subject of your paper?

Answer (score 4):

"Shadowed" is not used as much as "overshadowed". They both mean the same, but "shadowed" has a secondary meaning of being *behind* something else, so "overshadowed" would be clearer.